# Can the Jummah Khutbah be made in another language besides Arabic?

Tags: halal-haram, arabic, jumuah, language, khutbah

Can the Jummah Khutbah be made in another language besides Arabic
I dont know Arabic language 
many Indian mosque Jummah khutbah is Arabic language and some few mosque is traditional language
is prohibited in Islam Jummah Khutbah be made in another language besides Arabic?

Answer (score -1):

Primary Khutbah is always in Arabic Following the tradition of our prophet Mohammed (pbuh) and the explanation part is always in local language and it should be as people need to understand and refresh their Takwa everyweek or discuss the current major issues their community might be facing so the purpose of gathering is not just to say Jummah prayer but also to find solutions to the problems that community as whole is facing and achieving unity and brotherhood. As proven from saheeh sunnah or our prophet (pbuh).

Allah knows best.